# Removing from react array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I remove an item from an array in react? I've tried a couple of things and it didnt work out. Just trying to make a basic todo app. I've updated my post to provide the render method to show where the deleteTodo is going. I've also updated my deleteTodo with an answer I got from this post. It kind of works, the only problem is it deletes all of the items in the todo list rather than just the single one.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: "",
    todos: [{
        value: "walk the dog",
        done: false
      },
      {
        value: "do the dishes",
        done: false
      }
    ]
  }

  addTodo = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log('clicked')
    const newTodo = {
      value: this.state.inputValue,
      done: false
    }
    const todos = this.state.todos;
    todos.push(newTodo);
    this.setState({
      todos,
      inputValue: ''
    })
  }

  deleteTodo = (value) => {
    // Take copy of current todos
    const todos = [this.state.todos];
    const filteredTodos = todos.filter((item) => item.value !== value);
    this.setState({
      todos: filteredTodos
    }) 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form 
          addTodo={this.addTodo}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
        <List 
         todos={this.state.todos}
         deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you have to return true or false while using filter.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You might find the [MDN docs for `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) useful here

Comment: In `deleteTodo()`: try `const todos = [...this.state.todos]`. See [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `filter` appears to be the problem.. To create a new array of elements without the `value` using filter, you can try something like this:

EDIT: Updated answer with a full working demo

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.textRef = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); this.props.handleSubmit(this.textRef.current.value)}}>
                <input type="text" ref={this.textRef}/>
                <input type="submit" value="add"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class List extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.todos.map((todo) => (
                        <li key={todo.value}>
                            <p><input type="checkbox" checked={todo.done}/>{todo.value} </p>
                            <input type="button" onClick={() => (this.props.deleteTodo(todo.value))} value="delete"/>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        inputValue: "",
        todos: [{
            value: "walk the dog",
            done: false
        },
            {
                value: "do the dishes",
                done: false
            }
        ]
    }

    addTodo = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (value) => {
        const newTodo = {
            value,
            done: false
        }
        const todos = [...this.state.todos];
        todos.push(newTodo);
        this.setState({
            todos,
            inputValue: ''
        })
    }

    deleteTodo = (value) => {
        const todos = this.state.todos;
        const filteredTodos = todos.filter((item) => item.value !== value);
        this.setState({
            todos: filteredTodos
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Form
                    addTodo={this.addTodo}
                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                />
                <List
                    todos={this.state.todos}
                    deleteTodo={this.deleteTodo}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default App;
```

Also, I changed your `handleSubmit` method to create a new Array to keep in line with React's functional paradigm

Comment: I still cant seem to remove the todo item. I went back to make sure it was connected to the button I have and it work, but the solution still doesnt do anything unfortunately

Comment: Can you please update the question to include the render method so we can see how the event is being bound to the method and the value being passed to that function? Can you add a console.log in your deleteTodo method and print the value of `value` and check if it is coming through okay?

Comment: I tried to update the post, but the format requirements are a nightmare and I cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Go ahead and put the code up... Someone can edit to fix the formatting for you. I usually copy-paste the code into my IDE (I use VScode), select all, run the formatter, press tab to indent by 4 spaces and copy paste it back on SO.

Comment: updated it. I guess it wanted me to add a longer description

Comment: The part you have posted looks okay. I guess it really comes down to how those methods are invoked inside the `Form` and `List` component. I have updated my code to show example implementations of those methods. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter that value from array and set new filtered array in the `setState`.

```
deleteTodo = (value) => {
    // Take copy of current todos
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];
    const filteredTodos = todos.filter( (item) => item.value !== value);
  this.setState({
  todos: filteredTodos
```

})
      }

Comment: I'm getting somewhere with this, the only problem is that this solution deletes the entire list instead of just one item

Comment: Can you create working demo in jsfiddle and share the link. I can directly fix and share the solution with you.

Comment: I can try. I have more than one component and its giving me a ton of errors that im not getting in my editor

Comment: Are you talking about perf. here?

Answer (score 0):

i have used lodash for such this.
lodash is a library for doing such thing https://lodash.com/

if you can get the same value object that you inserted while adding the rest is quite easy

you lodash to find the index in which you have the object in the array
on your delete function

```
const todos = this.state.todos;
const itemToRemove = {value: "walk the dog",done: false};
var index = _.findIndex(todos, itemToRemove); 
const filteredTodos = todos.splice(index, 1)

this.setState({
  todos: filteredTodos
})
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Unfortunately, the [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in this solution `mutates` `this.state` and only returns the `itemToRemove` (not `filteredTodos`) 